# Gql query for repeated StructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do I write the following query in GQL? [1]

```py
Contact.query(Contact.address == Address(city='San Francisco',
                                         street='Spear St'))
```

[1] [Filtering for Structured Property Values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#gql , "To query models containing structured properties, you can use `foo.bar` in your GQL syntax to reference subproperties" -- so if I understand your task correctly,

```
'''SELECT * FROM Contact 
   WHERE address.city='San Francisco' AND
         address.street='Spear St'
'''
```

should work.  Doesn't it?

Comment: No, it does not. That query is the same as:  

    ` Contact.query(Contact.address.city == 'Amsterdam',  # Beware!
                             Contact.address.street == 'Spear St')`


>may find contacts with an address whose city is 'Amsterdam' and another (different) address whose street is 'Spear St'.

Comment: Looking at the source here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query#RepeatedStructuredPropertyPredicate I don't think the DB directly supports the query you are trying to do. I think the NDB lib is doing something like above and then verifying that the correct properties have the correct values "in memory" (at the application layer).